# Xcode test recording disabled, says "At least one test should be selected"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10.2, uitest

Xcode 10.2.1, iOS 12.2, iPhone 8 Simulator.

I am able to successfully test my app by manually writing my own tests, but I'm unable to record. The record button is disabled, and if I hover over it, Xcode says "At least one test should be selected":

[image]

There seems to be something else Xcode wants. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I had a separate target just for ui testing, and was having this issue.
I was able to enable the record button by editing the scheme for my main app target instead of working with the extra testing target.
Edit your main scheme and enable test and run for the ui test target:

[image]

See the 2 checkmarks near the bottom right?  That's what fixed it for me.

Comment: I found after doing this I had to quit Xcode and reopen it for it to work but this was indeed the key, thanks!

Comment: @StuP. Quitting and starting Xcode did the trick also for me. However, I did the changes above to adapt the settings for the Build-Targets, hence... this might also be needed.